# scoreManager.explainScore(solution) not working in Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner, quarkus

in the current Documentation of Optaplanner (7.40.0.Final) it says:

"The easiest way to explain the score during development is to print the return value of explainScore()"
When I create a `scoreManager` it doesn't have the method `explainScore()`

How do I get the explanation of the score in the Terminal? Where do I have to call the `scoreManager`?

I am working with Quarkus and my problem is very similar to the TimeTabling Problem.

Best regards and thank you in advance
Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the version coming with the Quarkus Platform BOM? Because in this case, it's 7.39.0.Final and that could explain your issue.

You can define the version yourself and upgrade to 7.40.0.Final. It might work, Geoffrey would be able to confirm.

He will also be able to tell you if he plans to upgrade Quarkus to 7.40.0.Final for 1.7.

Comment: Yes, we do. Here's the issue to track: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2071
We also need to think about including such changes as part of our release process.

Comment: The workaround is to import the optaplanner-bom 7.40 before importing the quarkus-universe-bom. That will work, because the optaplanner-bom only contains org.optaplanner dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

That method was introduce recently. OptaPlanner 7.40.0.Final, the same version as the docs you're reading, definitely has it:
https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/7.40.0.Final/optaplanner-core/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/core/api/score/ScoreManager.java#L81